# Hook to BroadcastReceiver using Xposed Framework

Tags: java, android, xposed

How to hook a onReceive method inside BroadcastReceiver?

```
public class RecentsActivity extends Activity
{
  mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the BroadcastReceiver is an abstract class and this is an inline class definition, perhaps you can retrieve this BroadcastReceiver this way:

```
for(Class<?> cls : <package_name>.RecentsActivity.class.getDeclaredClasses()){
    if(BroadcastReceiver.isAssignableFrom(cls)){
        //hook onReceive
    }
}
```

Otherwise try to check the application smali code using the [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/).

There probably is a file named RecentsActivity$N (where N is a number). Just do `Class.forName("<packagename>.RecentsActivity$N")` and hook this class onReceive method.

Good luck!

Comment: Your propositions don't work, because they are trying to find method in my application, not application which i want to hook. (maybe it will work when i use `param.getClass()` instead of `Class` but i didn't checked this). But solution is pretty simple, just normally use findAndHookMethod, only use class name from smali, ex. `com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity$1`